# Template Inheritance(Jinja2 Templating) - Flaws in my code or understanding of the concept

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have been trying to extend the index.html structure to other html pages and I am using the concept of Template Inheritance. Unfortunately, I seem to be facing trouble achieving the goal as templates do not extend the structure from the index html file that I am pointing to. Any pointers that can help me understand where I might be going wrong.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>EDS-API</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/main.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/cb28e3fd76.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navigation">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <h2>EDS</h2>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="login.html"><i class="fas fa-user"></i>Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i>Operations</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-file-medical-alt"></i>Claims</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i>Dashboard</a></li>
            </ul> 
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class=main_content>
        <header class="main_header">
            <div>EDS - Kickstart the engine and roll away.</div>  
        </header>
        <section class="main_body">
            <div>EDS - API</div>
        </section>
    </div>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Claims.html

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h3> Claims Data </h3>
{% endblock %}
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask,render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route("/claims")
def claims():
    return render_template('claims.html')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsI17.png)

Comment: Tell us more about what is happening. What does you `/claims` return? How about your file structure?

Comment: I just get a response on the file showing me the html tags as seen on the image that I have added and also pasted what I see.   It is the raw html content rather than the html structure of the index file that I am extending. Apologies for the late response. Thanks for looking into it.                                                                    {% extends "index.html" %} {% block content %}
Claims Data
{% endblock %}